# Outputting a 2D array using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I need to display a horizontal and vertical line with '*' using arrays and functions. 
Here is the problem description:

> You will create a program that can draw linestext into a
>   two-dimensional array of characters. Each character in the array will
>   represent one character to be displayed on the console output. This is
>   a character based graphics system. A line will be made up of a series
>   of “*” characters written either vertically or horizontally across the
>   display. Since we cannot write directly to the screen we will write
>   out graphics into a two-dimensional array and then write the display
>   out to the console via cout.

This is the code I have so far. The parts I need help on is what to put inside the functions. Thanks for the help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// global constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 79;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 74;
const char ON = '*';
const char OFF = ' ';
const char ERROR = '?';
const char NONE = '\0';

//function prototypes
void reset(char []);
void display(char []);
char getLine();
char getPixel();
char drawLine();
char drawPixel();

int main()
{
    // variables use below for the graphics
    int minX = 0;
    int maxX = SCREEN_WIDTH - 1;
    int midX = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
    int minY = 0;
    int maxY = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1;
    int midY = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;

    const int COORD = 2;

    int point1;
    int newX, newY;
    char ch;
    char null = '\0';

    const int STR_PTS = 16;
    string string1 = "1{2}3[4]5@6#7%8^";
    int points[STR_PTS][COORD] = { {minX + 2, minY + 2}, { minX + 3, minY + 2 }, { midX -     3, minY + 2 }, { midX - 2, minY + 2 },
    { minX + 2, midY - 2 }, { minX + 3, midY - 2 }, { midX - 3, midY - 2 }, { midX - 2,     midY - 2 },
{ midX - 3, midY }, { minX + 4, maxY + 1 },
{ midX - 1, midY }, { maxX + 2, minY + 4 },
{ midX + 1, midY }, { minX + 1, minY - 1 },
{ midX + 3, midY }, { minX + 3, minY - 4 } };

// graphics "screen". Memory to be displayed on the console
char screen[SCREEN_WIDTH][SCREEN_HEIGHT];

// clear out the graphics screen
reset(screen);

// Test of part 1
// We are going to test drawPixel in the upper left corner of the output
for (point1 = 0; point1 < STR_PTS; point1++)
{
    // draw a char at the x, y coord in points
    drawPixel(screen, points[point1][0], points[point1][1], string1[point1]);
}

// Test of part 2
// Next we will test getPixel and drawLine
newX = midX;
newY = minY + 2;

// for all of the character position (points) we wrote to before we will 
// try and read from those positions now. Only 4 of them are valid. 
for (point1 = 0; point1 < STR_PTS; point1++)
{
    // draw a char at the x, y coord in points
    ch = getPixel(screen, points[point1][0], points[point1][1]);

    if (ch == null)
    {
        ch = '-';
    }

    drawPixel(screen, newX, newY, ch);
    newY++;
}

// Now test 4 valid lines. Left to right, right to left, top to bottom and bottom to top
drawLine(screen, minX + 10, midY / 3, midX - 10, midY / 3);
drawPixel(screen, minX + 9, midY / 3, 'A');
drawLine(screen, midX - 10, midY / 3 + 3, minX + 10, midY / 3 + 3);
drawPixel(screen, midX - 9, midY / 3 + 3, 'B');
drawLine(screen, maxX - 10, minY + 3, maxX - 10, midY - 3);
drawPixel(screen, maxX - 10, midY - 2, 'C');
drawLine(screen, maxX - 12, midY - 3, maxX - 12, minY + 3);
drawPixel(screen, maxX - 12, minY + 2, 'D');
// Now test a line that is not vertical or horizontal
drawLine(screen, minX, minY + 3, minX + 3, minY + 6);
drawPixel(screen, minX + 1, minY + 4, 'E');

// Test clipped lines - one that is clipped on the right, one is clipped on the left,
//  one is clipped on the top, one is clipped on the bottom and one is entirely off of the screen
drawLine(screen, maxX - 5, midY / 2, maxX + 10, midY / 2);
drawPixel(screen, maxX - 6, midY / 2, 'F');
drawLine(screen, minX - 10, midY / 2, minX + 5, midY / 2);
drawPixel(screen, minX + 6, midY / 2, 'G');
drawLine(screen, maxX - 15, minY - 10, maxX - 15, minY + 10);
drawPixel(screen, maxX - 15, minY + 11, 'H');
drawLine(screen, maxX - 2, maxY - 10, maxX - 2, maxY + 10);
drawPixel(screen, maxX - 2, maxY - 11, 'I');
drawLine(screen, maxX + 2, midY, maxX + 20, midY);
drawPixel(screen, maxX - 2, maxY - 13, 'J');

dispaly(screen);  // output to the console via cout

return 0;
}

void reset(char screen[SCREEN_WIDTH][SCREEN_HEIGHT])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < SCREEN_WIDTH; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < SCREEN_HEIGHT; col++)
        {
            screen[row][col] = OFF;
        }
    }
}


void dispaly(char screen[SCREEN_WIDTH][SCREEN_HEIGHT])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < SCREEN_WIDTH; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < SCREEN_HEIGHT; col++)
        {
            screen[row][col];
        }
    }
}

char getPixel(char screen[SCREEN_WIDTH][SCREEN_HEIGHT], int x, int y)
{
    for (int index = x; index < 5; index++)
    {
        screen[index][y] = ON;
    }
}

char drawPixel(char screen[SCREEN_WIDTH][SCREEN_HEIGHT], int x, int y, char charValue)
{
    getPixel;
    if (x >= 0 && x < 79 && y >= 0 && y < 74)
    {
        cout << ON;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << NONE;
    }

    return charValue;
}

char getLine()
{

}

char drawLine(char screen[SCREEN_WIDTH][SCREEN_HEIGHT], int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
{
    drawPixel;
    if (startX == endX)
    {
        startY <= endY;
        startY >= endY;
    }
    else if (startY == endY)
    {
        startX <= endX;
        startX >= endX;
    }
    else if (startX > endX)
    {
        temp = startX;
        startX = endX;
        endX = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are so many problems in that code that it's difficult to suggest anything other than for you to take out your book, start reading from the beginning, and do all the earlier exercises. Then do this one for the one-dimensional case (i.e. a line).